# Strange situation to get a Segmentation Fault

Tags: linux, sockets, segmentation-fault

A friend of mine gave me a project in c to work on a project in Linux with sockets.(tic tac toe)
The project has already the executable files and the program works nice.

When I delete the executable files and compile the program myself I get no errors, but there is a certain situation on the program (when I challenge other player to a game) where I get a segmentation fault, and with the original executable files I get no error in this situation.

I didn't change anything on the program, just removed the previous executable files and compiled the program myself, I have no idea why this is happening.

Theoretically there is any explanation?

Comment: Its possible the code relies on undefined behaviour.  Your friend may have been unlucky and found a compiler version + build command that didn't show this up.  If you know roughly where the fault occurs, post the relevant code and you'll get more specific help.

Comment: I'd look out for uninitialized members...

Comment: This is very typical UB problems, such as out of bounds variable usage or uninitialized variables - these problems, particularly the uninitialized variables, can vary quite a bit depending on compiler version, which order functions are called, or simply what happened in a function call before this one.

Comment: just for you to know, the problem is in a part of the code where the program uses the strtok, I guess the other compiler ignored the problem but my compiler does not.Now i just have try to fix this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is a usual case when you use different versions of compilers, libraries, utilities  etc etc.. No wonder that big projects (as Linux Kernel) explicitly define what version of tools you should use to get the expected results. Firstly, try to recompile again using the **same compiler** as you friend does, if that does not help, dig deeper - libraries, utilities..